# JQuery append with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to post certain blocks of code every time an Ajax call is loaded. I am using Append to do it and it looks like this:

```
$("#wrap").append("
   <div class='newData'>
     <div class='infoBox'>
       " + firstName + lastName + "
     </div>
   </div>"
);
```

My Ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "feed.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            firstName = data[i].First_Name;
            lastName = data[i].Last_Name;

           // wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">' + firstName + lastName +'</div>';
            $("#wrap").append("
              <div class='newData'>
                <div class='infoBox'>
              " + firstName + lastName + "
                </div>
              </div>");
          }
        }
    });
```

When I try to do this nothing comes up. If I take out the `infoBox` div I get it to work. Is this the proper way to do this. I will be adding multiple different divs inside of this with variables from my Ajax call. Are there better ways to do this or is this the right approach but done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't concatenating it properly.

It should look like this:

```
 $("#wrap").append("<div class='newData'>" +
                      "<div class='infoBox'>" +
                        firstName + lastName + 
                      "</div>" +
                   "</div>");
```

Comment: Awesome I understand. Is this the general way to approach this or are there better techniques?

Comment: @RightLeftRight12 Yeah I believe so. Not sure if better, but what I usually do is to put the blocks inside a variable then call it when it's needed. E.g. `var block="<div>...</div>";` then using it `$("#wrap").append(block);`